# Image compression using orthogonal polynomial Transformation

Tags: matlab, image-compression, orthogonal

I am working on Image compression based on orthogonal polynomial transformation. My input image is gray scale image of size 256*256. i divide this image into 4 by 4 blocks. and than apply the orthogonal polynomial operator on each block. but I am not getting  correct coefficient.

Example:

If I have a block 4*4 of Input image,`I=[5 11 8 10;9 8 4 12; 1 10 11 4;19 6 15 7]`; and my polynomial operator for `n=4` is `[M] = [p0 p1 p2 p3]=[1 -3 1 -3;1 -1 -1 9;1 1 -1 -9;1 3 1 3]`. After finding the `outer product=[20 -24 24 -16; -24 84 -80 24;24 -80 84 -24;-16 24 -24 20]` when I applied this on input image blocks, my answer is `[-396 172 88 -104; 1012 -248 -376 616 -972 320 436 -552; 492 -104 4 172]` which is wrong. It should be `[140 0 -6 -10; 32 -112 2 -174; 22 -30 8 -40;34 -54 84 -8]`, what I have done wrong?

My `MATLAB` code to find orthogonal polynomial operator is given below.

```
u(1,1:4)=1;
n=4;
mu=(n+1)/2;   %mean
t=1:4;
u(2,:)=t-mu;
for i=2:3
b(i,:)=((i).^2*(((n).^2)-(((i).^2))))/(4*(4*((i).^2)-1));
u(i+1,:)=(t-mu).*u(i,:)-b(i,:).*u(i-1,:);
end
u;
M=u;
```